# How to use multiple checked data-binds on a single radio button using KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, knockout.js

The user needs to select one radio button. My label needs to have the value of the selected radio button to display later in a text box. I also need the value of the radio button to be stored in the Ajax "title" variable so that I can use it on the backend (Python - Flask). When I click my migrate button, it runs my Ajax call.

I read that I can just put commas between data-binds, but by doing `data-bind="checked: $data.title, checked: radioFrom"`, it breaks my code to where the radio buttons don't work. However, if I just do `data-bind="checked: $data.title"`, then my Ajax call works, but my label remains blank (for obvious reasons).

How do I get it so that I can use two checked data-binds on my radio buttons so that my label updates and my Ajax calls work? Or is there another solution that I'm missing?

**My header**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20150503/json2.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <body>  
        {% extends "layout.html" %}
        {% block content %}
        <div id="tab">
```

**My Radio Buttons**

```
<td id="myRadioFrom" class="label">From:</td>
<td>
    <label><input type="radio" value="DevQ" name="from" data-bind="checked: $data.title, checked: radioFrom" />DevQ</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="Dev2" name="from" data-bind="checked: $data.title, checked: radioFrom" />Dev2</label>
</td>
```

**My Label**

```
<tr>
    <td class="label">From:</td>
    <td data-bind="text: radioFrom"></td>
</tr>
```

**My Button**

```
<form>
    <span class="migrate"><button data-bind="click: $data.add" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Migrate!" data-dismiss="modal">Migrate!</button></span>
</form>
```

**My Javascript/KnockoutJS**

```
<script>
    var TabViewModel = function(){
        var self = this;

        //Set href value of element
        self.selected = ko.observable(null);

        self.tasksURI = 'http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks';    // Use to get root access to server
        self.username = "";
        self.password = "";
        self.tasks = ko.observableArray();

        self.radioFrom = ko.observable("");

        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");                 
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        controls.onchange = function() {
            console.log(viewModel.radioFrom());
        }

        self.ajax = function(uri, method, data)
        {
            var request = 
            {
                url: uri,
                type: method,
                contentType: "application/json",
                accepts: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),

                // beforeSend is invoked by jQuery, used to send a jqXHR object to get a request from $.aJax
                beforeSend: function (xhr)
                {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                        "Basic " + btoa(self.username + ":" + self.password));
                },
                // if $.aJax request comes back with an error such as invalid username
                error: function(jqXHR)
                {
                    console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
                }               
            };
            return $.ajax(request); // Returns value of the $.aJax request
        }

        self.add = function(task)
        {
            self.ajax(self.tasksURI, 'POST', task).done(function(data)
            {
                self.tasks.push
                ({
                    uri: ko.observable(data.task.uri),
                    title: ko.observable(data.task.title),
                    description: ko.observable(data.task.description),
                    done: ko.observable(data.task.done)
                });

            });
        }

    };
    window.viewModel = new TabViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel, $('#tab')[0]);          
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use multiple bindings on a single control, but what you are attempting to do is use multiple of the SAME binding on a single control. If you apply the same type of binding to the control knockout will select the second usage of the same binding. You probably don't want to do this.

The value held in `title` is updated to contain the value of the value attribute of the radio button that is currently selected i.e. `value="DevQ"` or `value="Dev2"` in your inputs. This means that the value stored in `$data.title` **is** precisely what you're looking for! i.e. the radio button whose value you need. Take a look at the snippet below. It hope it helps clear things up for you.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  title: ko.observable('DevQ')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="radio" value="DevQ" name="from" data-bind="checked: title" />DevQ</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" value="Dev2" name="from" data-bind="checked: title" />Dev2</label>
<br/>
<hr/>
<br/>The value held in title() is updated to contain the value of the value attribute of the radio button that is selected
<br/>
<br/>
<b id="myRadioFrom" class="label">From: </b><span data-bind="text: $data.title"></span>
```

Comment: My current `ko.applybindings` looks like this `ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel, $('#tab')[0]);`.
How should I apply bindings in my scenario?

Comment: You can simply use `var tabViewModel = new TabViewModel();` and then `ko.applyBindings(tabViewModel, document.getElementById(tab));`

Comment: I get this error when I try what you have above...
`knockout-min.js:63 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "checked: function (){return title }"
Message: title is not defined`. How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same binding twice on one element, at least not with the built in bindings.

Instead, you should structure your view models in a way that each function has access to the relevant scope.

Typically, I tend to have a root or parent view model that wires up Ajax requests, and have smaller view models for domain concepts like a `task`. For example:

```js
// Fake jQuery ajax stuff:
var $ = { ajax: function(options) { console.log(options); } };

function Task() {
  this.title = ko.observable("");
}

function RootVm() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.user = ko.observable("fake-username");
  self.password = ko.observable("sec!ret");
  
  self.tasks = ko.observableArray([new Task(), new Task()]);
  
  function doAjaxCall(task) {
    $.ajax({
      data: task.title(),
      user: self.user(),
      password: self.password()
    });
  }
  
  self.migrate = function(task) {
    doAjaxCall(task);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootVm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks">
  <li>
    Title:
    <input data-bind="textInput: title">
    <button data-bind="click: $root.migrate">migrate</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr>

User: <input data-bind="textInput: user"><br>
Password: <input data-bind="textInput: password">
```

Comment: I'm a little lost. Could you provide some examples from my specific code?